# How to change object into array to create mutil record in sails.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sails.js

i'm trying to create a mutil records with sails ver 1.2.3

with input:

```
{
    "selectedDog": [5,9,12] // dog id
    "checkInTime": "12h",
    "checkInDate": "2012-12-12",
    "nameOfService": "Hotel",
    "typeOfService": "Luxury"
}
```

How can i create mutil records with every booking have information like this

```
{

"pets": 5 // dog id
    "checkInTime": "12h",
    "checkInDate": "2012-12-12",
    "nameOfService": "Hotel",
    "typeOfService": "Luxury"

},
{

"pets": 9 // dog id
    "checkInTime": "12h",
    "checkInDate": "2012-12-12",
    "nameOfService": "Hotel",
    "typeOfService": "Luxury"

},{

"pets": 12 // dog id
    "checkInTime": "12h",
    "checkInDate": "2012-12-12",
    "nameOfService": "Hotel",
    "typeOfService": "Luxury"

}
```

My pet model:

```
bla bla

booking: {
      collection: 'booking',
      via: 'pets'
    },
```

my booking model:

```
bla bla

pets: {
      model: 'pets'
    }
```

i tried to use .createEach() but i need to change input into array like this:

```
[{
  pets: 5,
  "checkInTime": "12h",
    "checkInDate": "2012-12-12",
    "nameOfService": "Hotel",
    "typeOfService": "Luxury"
},
{..},
{..}
]
```

and i dont know how. Notice that could be more *selectedDog* or less

anyone have a solution?

Comment: Sorry, why this question marked as `mysql`?

Comment: sorry i added by mistake

Comment: @Trouble you might want to check this if new dependency is ok for you: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Answer (score 0):

So basically i have to use `.forEach()` and a loop
here is my answer

```
infor.forEach(dog => {
      for (let id of dog.selectedDog) {
        data = {
         checkInTime: dog.checkInTime,
          checkInDate: dog.checkInDate,

          nameOfService: dog.nameOfService,
          typeOfService: dog.typeOfService,

          pets: id
        };
        array.push(data);
      }
    });
```